# Why I can't find davfs2 package in opensuse repositories?

Tags: opensuse, webdav

```
$ sudo zypper se davfs
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
No matching items found.
$ sudo zypper se davfs2
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
No matching items found.
```

I don't want use programs such cadaver, etc

Why is it so problematic in this distro?

My repos

```
http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/repo/oss/
http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/
http://download.opensuse.org/debug/tumbleweed/repo/oss/
http://download.opensuse.org/tumbleweed/repo/non-oss/
http://download.opensuse.org/source/tumbleweed/repo/oss/
http://download.opensuse.org/update/tumbleweed/
https://repo.skype.com/rpm/stable/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zypper works only with the repositories you have installed.

When you do not find a package in zypper it is a good practice to:

1) Search them in http://software.opensuse.org for your openSUSE

- See [http://software.opensuse.org/package/davfs2?search_term=davfs2](http://software.opensuse.org/package/davfs2?search_term=davfs)

2) Or add the repositories that have your package

```
$ sudo zypper ar -f http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/filesystems/openSUSE_Tumbleweed "OBS: Filesystems"
$ sudo zypper refresh
$ sudo zypper install davfs2
```